# split 24 hours into hour range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to split 24 hrs into hour range like

```
0000-0001,0001-0002 ....
```

and save them in a table as

```
 Time Range
 0000-0001
 0001-0002
```

This is what I have tried

```
RIGHT ('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh,time)), 2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(hh,time) + 1), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE for the hours, and some simple string manipulation for the output:

```
with hrs (time)
AS
(
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT time+1
    FROM hrs WHERE time<23
)
select time,
RIGHT ('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, time), 4) + '-' + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, time + 1), 4)
from hrs
```

Output:

```
0   0000-0001
1   0001-0002
2   0002-0003
3   0003-0004
4   0004-0005
5   0005-0006
6   0006-0007
7   0007-0008
8   0008-0009
9   0009-0010
10  0010-0011
11  0011-0012
12  0012-0013
13  0013-0014
14  0014-0015
15  0015-0016
16  0016-0017
17  0017-0018
18  0018-0019
19  0019-0020
20  0020-0021
21  0021-0022
22  0022-0023
23  0023-0024
```